# How MOVB, TSTB and all byte instructions works in odd address read in PDP11?

Tags: pdp-11

I'm writing a PDP11 emulator. When CPU read odd address on Unibus odd address exception is launched. But the code below INC increments PRTPTR by 1 which make TSTB @PRTPTR generate a exception when it try access odd address.

```
PRTAST:
    TSTB @PRTPTR
    BEQ 2$
    MOVB @PRTPTR,@#177566
    INC PRTPTR
    RTT
2$: CLRB @#177564
    RTT
```

How MOVB and TSTB and all byte instructions work with odd address?

Answer (score 9):

As far as the Unibus is concerned, all reads are word-sized (and from an even address), and the CPU simply ignores the portion of the word it wasn't interested in.  Thus, to read an odd-address byte, the CPU reads the even-address word containing that byte, and uses only the top 8 bits of the result.

Unibus writes are allowed to be byte-sized (there are 2 separate write cycle types: DATO and DATOB, which correspond to word-write and byte-write respectively).  Word writes are always to even addresses, but byte writes may specify an odd address.  Note however that for a byte written to an odd address, the byte value must occupy the *upper* 8 bits of the Unibus data lines (i.e. it can be thought of as a word write with the lower even byte masked out).  To put it another way, for a DATOB byte write cycle, the lowest address bit is treated as a flag indicating whether the byte of the Unibus data word that is intended to be modified is the upper one, or the lower one.

Q-Bus works the same way -- reads are always word-sized, and writes may be either word or byte sized, with byte-sized writes using the upper or lower byte depending on whether the address is odd or even.

Comment: Does Q-Bus work exactly the same for word and byte access?

Comment: Yes, although the actual bus signals used are different.  I suppose I should have mentioned that, even though the original question referred to Unibus explicitly.  I'll edit that in, thanks for bringing my attention to it.

Comment: `TSTB @PRTPTR` is a DATI cycle Unibus. When `@PRTPTR` is odd DATI fail or not? Is DATI with odd address permitted?

Comment: @Fabio DATI is a read cycle.  So the whole word is read over the bus and the CPU ignores the irrelevant half.